# How to watch sass folder for changes without compiling in css in react

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Curreny my scripts in package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/styles/ -o src/styles/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/styles/ -o src/styles/ --watch --recursive"
  }
```

When I type **npm run watch-css** It watches and compiles all my scss files into css. And I import compiled css file in my react component like this **import '../styles/component.css'**

I need to find a way to import not css file but scss file and with special command like **npm run watch-scss** see all the changes I make in my scss file.

PS: I'm using create-react-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CRA abstracts away the build configuration logic for simplicity. If you want to add custom build logic, you need to opt out of the abstracted version using this command: `npm run eject`

This will run a script to expose the webpack build configurations. From there, you need to add a sass loader for webpack.

guide: https://medium.com/@Connorelsea/using-sass-with-create-react-app-7125d6913760

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@import "some_style.scss";
```

in your sass file.